# Xamarin forms: how to assigning list to listview

Tags: listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms

.CS file:

```
//Creating connection to website
Connection connect=new Connection();
List<News> newsList=new List<News>(connect.Handshake(Select.News));
for (int i = 0; i < newsList.Count; i++)
{
   NewsList.ItemsSource = newsList[i].title;
}
```

XAML file:

```
<ListView x:Name="NewsList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Margin="6,4,6,4">
                    <Label Text="{Binding title}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The first line create the connection where it connect to website and parse data. Handshake(Select.News) returns a List.
List isn't empty but after running I am getting an empty list. How can I fix that? Thanks!

Comment: You need to set the `ItemsSource` property on the `ListView` and bind it to your `NewsList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
NewsList.ItemsSource = newsList;
```

Instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < newsList.Count; i++)
{
    NewsList.ItemsSource = newsList[i].title;
}
```

And if possible to use `ViewModel`, then you can use observable collection instead of list and binding collection on `Itemsource`.